# running bash script from php

Tags: php, linux, bash

When I run it(bash script) on the linux machine from cmd I get **online** as output but when I run it remotely from other machine's browser I get **offline** as output.
My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=10 --spider http://google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "online"
else
    echo "offline"
fi
```

My PHP script is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>
This is the title
</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$output=shell_exec('/home/pi/checkonline.sh');
echo $output;
?>
</body></html>
```

Note: I am hosting the web server on raspberry pi 2 running raspbian OS,php5,apache2.
I use **proxyserver** to connect to internet, I have successfully configured it in apt.conf as well as export http_proxy, so that will not be the problem.

Comment: Does the php script work when executed via command line?

Comment: yes, running php from command line gives online as output. @jedifans

Comment: Remove the "-q" argument to wget and replace it with "-v". See what wget prints. It might very well be that SElinux, Apparmor, or a similar watchdog prevents you from running wget from the Apache2 server process.

Comment: Still the same it prints **offline** in the brower, but in the terminal **php5 .../bash.php** gives long output as connected ok and at last **online**.

Comment: Try to set proxy settings right before wget execution `http_proxy=$your_value wget ...` or export it before wget in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full path of wget

`WGET=/usr/bin/wget`

`WGET='which wget'` <-- use backquotes

Comment: tried using full path still doesn't work in browser, while running php from command line gives online as output

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your script in same folder as your php script and add execution permission. as for me it's working and printing online.
`sudo chmod +x checkonline.sh`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>
This is the title
</title></head>
<body>
<h1>output</h1>
<?php
$output=shell_exec('./checkonline.sh');
echo $output;
?>
</body></html>

#!/bin/bash
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=10 --spider http://www.google.com
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "online"
else
    echo "offline"
fi
```

Comment: Copied your code and did the same thing as described above still in browser it gives offline and in terminal it gives online, _could proxy be a problem since am using internet behind a proxy server, maybe apache2 needs it's proxy configured too_